# Unable to see anything after importing .obj file

Tags: objects, 3d-view, import, obj

I'm trying to import .obj files from [Life Science Database of Body Parts](http://dbarchive.biosciencedbc.jp/en/bodyparts3d/download.html) the files contain Polygon Mesh Data.

When I import the obj file into Blender, the *Outliner* shows a new mesh object was added, but nothing is visible in the 3D viewport:

[image: Import]

[image: Nothing Visible]

How can I solve invisible or missing objects after importing from STL, OBJ, FBX, PLY or any other exchange file formats?

Comment: you might have to zoom in. In 3dview hit period (with the object selected)

Comment: Got it. The problem was with "origin" of the mesh, which was way outside the actual substance of the mesh. As a result, I was seeing the origin in the center of the viewport while the mesh was way outside (and as a result not visible until I zoomed out considerably).

Comment: I think it's a bug. I had this too several times. I noticed that sometimes when you import an object it does not do that loading animation and immediately shows an empty mesh in the outliner. I know its empty because when I `tab` into it, it shows 0/0 vertices in the below status bar. I usually fix this by closing blender and opening it again. There usually is a little loading animation when the import successfully works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Imported objects from other file formats, are often times really small, off centered, or very far away from scene origin, compared to the default scene scale.

First step is to make sure anything was actually imported. Look in the *Outliner* for new objects under current collection (geometry should be of mesh type). If there are any, use the *Outliner* to select them.

[image]

Then with the mouse over the *3D View* press the <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (Period) key, or go to *View > Frame Selected* for 2.8+, to view selected objects.
This will zoom in tightly on the selected object.

[image]

If the objects are too small or too big in relation to default scene scale you may still be able to see them due to being outside the view distance bounds.

If that is the case you may been to adjust clipping distances, either for the [viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport), [camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance) or both.

Working with scene scales too large or too small may lead to float point precision issues. Blender and Cycles render are set up to work best with 1 Blender Unit = 1 Meter, both in terms of lighting and physics. If your objects are in millimetres, Kilometres or very far from this scale range you may want to scale them up or down to fit roughly in that scale range, to avoid future issues.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is FIRST checking the *Dimensions*. Select the object in the *Outliner* and press <kbd>N</kbd> then change the dimension to something below 20m (The cube is 2m) but use the *Scale* field so it's proportional. In this case I changed 1.000 to 0.001). Then press <kbd>NumPad .</kbd> and instantly you will see your object.

[image]

Comment: Thants for your brilliant advice.