# obj file not displayed properly

Tags: import

I've an issue with an obj file.
Importing this file in blender:
http://156.54.99.175/3d/model.obj
the mesh not appear. Only by rotating and zooming-out something apperas, but not the whole geometry.

With other CAD and obj viewer the mesh is displayed correctly.
What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is there, the it's huge (like 500m tall) press <kbd>Numpad Period</kbd> to display it. If the object is showing partially you might need to adjust the clip distance. Then you should scale your model down to something more usable... [image]