# Cannot rotate sun lamp after importing OBJ file

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I created a new scene, deleted the cube and imported this OBJ file (created in FormZ). After that I did not see the scene but after following up [Cegaton's advices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/obj-file-not-displayed-properly) the scene showed up (but I must say I don't really understand what I am doing).

After that I moved the lamp and made it a sunlamp. Somehow I cannot rotate the lamp to point it to the house in the scene. I don't understand that.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a viewport bug in relation to the scene scale. Switch the lamp type from *Sun* to *Spot*, zoom into the scene and you'll see the *cone* of the spot light. If someone else can confirm this behavior, please report that to the official bug tracker.

Comment: Yes, the scene scale is very weird. I have set the clipping scale at 10000 ??Is this scale issue something that can be dealt with in FormZ when creating the OBJ file ? The same scene in 3DS has not these scale issues. When I import that file I don't have to scale up