# Why when importing an obj file nothing appears even when zooming?

Tags: mesh, import, transforms, units, external-applications

I have opened a new blender file and deleted the default cube, then imported an obj file . I did not see any thing so i selected it and i zoomed ,nothing appears.In the outliner i saw the object name ,But in the info panel i see that there isn't any verts/faces/edges.

When i opened the obj file in a text editor i found Mesh data in it. I tired this in all blender versions (2.78c/2.78.5/7.9). Can any one help how to view the mesh?

[image]

Comment: this could simply be a matter of scale. Blender uses meters as default units, whereas other systems tend to use centimeters, millimeters or inches. Try selecting the object in the outliner, and in the transform panel of the 3D view, enter 0.001 for all three scales.

Comment: @aliasguru but he also says "there isn't any verts/faces/edges"... how could it be? my guess is that what is in the obj could be corrupted or not supported maybe.

Comment: so how can i supported in blender ?

Comment: I' m sure this obj file contains mesh data, but blender can't read it

Comment: How big is that OBJ? Can you provide it somehow? Also, let us know what the info panel and the system console outputs, maybe there's an error message there.

Comment: @m.ardito One possibility is that the OP is in local layers mode. The model is imported on an invisible layer accidentally. In that case, you would see a mesh in the outliner, but nothing in the viewport, and the header would report zero faces, verts and edges, even though everything's there.

Comment: Actually the file is very small (38.7 KB). But Contains many lines of data

Comment: The object was completely deleted in edit mode. Only the origin point is left.

Comment: @LeoNas So how can i import the file without deleting it ?

Comment: Try to share your object as a zip file using google drive link or so, to get the original, and check

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you have to check is if there are any objects on the [Outliner Window](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html).

[image]

If there are, that means that you've successfully imported something. Then is just a matter of finding where it is and at what scale it was imported.

Select the object in the outliner and pres <kbd>Numpad Period</kbd> to center the display on the object.

---

You might need to adjust the [Clipping Distances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/sidebar.html#view-panel) on the 3D viewport's properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) if the object is too large or too small:

**Blender 2.8x**

[image]

**Blender 2.7x**

[image]

Sometimes the mesh can far away from the actual origin of the object. In that case it might take a bit longer to find the geometry, as the  Numpad period  will center the view on the origin. In that case you can enter Edit Mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, press <kbd>A</kbd> to "select all" of the geometry and press  numpad Period  again this time to center on the selected vertices.

Read: [Unable to see anything after importing .obj file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file) and [obj file not displayed properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/obj-file-not-displayed-properly/36303#36303)

Comment: This also doesn't work. i tried to press numpad period.

Comment: but how Can I adjust the clip distances on the viewport ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL1Vb.png

Comment: i made it but it does not work , but what i noticed that in the properties panel i found that the three dimensions is zero, scale is 1 for all and the rotation is 90 in the 'x'. i think that can be the problem.

Comment: The object was completely deleted in edit mode. Only the origin point is left.

Comment: To add to cegaton's answer, I just tried it with 2.79b 64-bit on Windows 10 and merely left-clicking on an item in the outliner and pressing numpad period does not work. It sometimes works when you right-click on the item in the outliner and choose 'Select'.