# When I import OBJ file it does not show

Tags: animation, mesh, materials, modifiers, obj

I have imported this file before an it has worked but not this time. I have pressed Numpad . and that just zooms me into here the picture below. I am not in local view.Last time it worked it had imported absolutely huge bugs scaling it down doesn't seem to work. thanks for your help!

[image: obj file not showing but strange blurriness]

Comment: Look like from the red line at the left that your object have huge dimension compared to your clipping view (in the N panel) change distance view (1km or 500km or 0.1m depending on the size of your object, EEVEE will have bug if difference between clipping start and end are too huge) Cycles with CPU will work best.

Comment: Hello, please press N or click on the left facing arrow in the top right of the 3D view, and go into the item panel. This will tell you the dimensions of your object. Please post these :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to see anything after importing .obj file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file) and [Why when importing obj file nothing appears](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89710/why-when-importing-an-obj-file-nothing-appears-even-when-zooming) and [imported object shows too small](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88007/imported-obj-shows-too-small) and [cannot see imported models](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107626/cannot-see-imported-models)

Comment: I have the same problem, but i cannot find the object in my viewport when i import it. scale doesn't work, from the N panel, the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The size of your import is very small.

You can use the <kbd>S</kbd>  key to scale the object.