# When i Import an obj it imports far away from the origin

Tags: import, error

Title says all
how do i make it so the obj is imported to the origin, it was working fine yesterday...

Comment: Once again the title shouldn't say it all. Put some effort into your questions, describe your issue thoroughly, state what steps you tried to fix the issue and most importantly search before posting. These are very basic questions that have been asked before numerous times

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/obj-file-not-displayed-properly/36303#36303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any model imported will have it's coordinates where they are in the file. There is nothing to fix here since the problem is not in Blender or importing, but in the file.

Imported objects are selected after importing, so just after importing you can set the origin to its center of geometry:

[image]

And then you can snap it to cursor that you can place anywhere you wish:

[image]

Comment: ok thanks sir i appreciate your help :)