# Import DAE (collada) does nothing

Tags: import, collada

I am importing a DAE file (a couple of different ones, acutally) and in both cases I get nothing in my scene.

The Blender Scene shows only render Layers and World, no geometry or objects.

How do we debug this? Is there a Log or something that tells us what is failing?
I get no errors, messages, nothing.

I am using the Collada importer that came with Blender 2.78... is there another importer I should rather use?

These DAE files do not come from Sketchup... Does it matter?

thank you

Gio

Comment: Look through related answer here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file. There is a console where all actions are printed, see [how to open it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)

Comment: What version of Blender?

Answer (score 0):

This is more for reference for other users having issues with the DAE Format.

It could be that the Collada DAE version being used for your assets is 1.4.0, where as Blender only seems to read 1.4.1

Try using Autodesk's FBX Converter tool on the DAE files and you will be able to use your files in Blender.