# Blender (v3.2.1) does not load in DAE file (DAE v1.4.1)

Tags: import, collada, dae

I'm trying to import [this DAE file](https://github.com/osrf/vrx/blob/master/wamv_description/models/WAM-V-Base/mesh/WAM-V-Base.dae) into blender to view the normals of the mesh file. However, when attempting to import the above DAE file I get the following console log:

```
Read prefs: /home/acxz/.config/blender/3.2/config/userpref.blend
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory
+-- Collada Import parameters------
| input file      : /home/acxz/vcs/git/github/nswc-pcd-heron-stochastic-control/vrx_ws/src/vrx/wamv_description/models/WAM-V-Base/mesh/WAM-V-Base.dae
| use units       : no
| autoconnect     : no
+-- Armature Import parameters ----
| find bone chains: no
| min chain len   : 0
| fix orientation : no
| keep bind info  : no
| import Image: /home/acxz/vcs/git/github/nswc-pcd-heron-stochastic-control/vrx_ws/src/vrx/wamv_description/models/WAM-V-Base/mesh/WamV.png
Sax FWL (Warning): Texture with sid "WamV_png-image" not found in effect with id "WamV_ncl1_1-fx".
+----------------------------------
| Collada Import : OK
+----------------------------------
```

Notice the warning and the subsequent `OK` given by blender on the successful import.

The Scene collection has not changed whatsoever and the object has not even been registered as loading in based on the top right hierarchy under Scene Collection.

Using blender v3.2.1 and using DAE file version 1.4.1.
OS: Linux (Archlinux)

The following similar question, [Import DAE (collada) does nothing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/import-dae-collada-does-nothing) has an answer which only mentions to use DAE file version 1.4.1 which I am already using.