# Why wont my imported obj appear, it says its in blender but I cant actually see it

Tags: objects, import

basically, in the little sidebar on the right, it has everything and it shows that my object is in the blender, but when I look at the actual grid thing, there are arrows and I'm able to move an invisible something however the object I can't see it (its a Roblox Character)

Comment: usually the issue is with the scale. Youe model might be too big or too small.https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when a 3d model is exported then imported, it can be imported really far away and/or really small. Its origin may be displaced. What you can do is select the object and then in the top left go to 3d cursor so you are moving the 3d cursor. Then move the 3d cursor to a place were you can see. Then select the move option at the top left and select the object in the heirarchy. then right click in the 3d view port and select: set origin> Geometry to origin. The object should be at the cursor. If you cant see it still, try scaling it up as much as possible. Hope this helps.