# Import of DXF File doesn't work, or more precisely nothing happens

Tags: import

Actually I have no clue at all how blender works. Still I have to try to work with it for a project at work. But I can't get started at all.

I have four 3D4 models (of hole saws) made in CAD and got .DWG files delivered. As my research shows it's only possible to import .DXF to blender. I managed to made the import option available and used ODA File Converter to convert .DWG > . DXF

Now I'm stuck trying to import the .DXF File in Blender. I chose a file and want to import, but nothing happens at all, not even an error message.

I tried google and everything. Also tried to Convert DWG > DXF > FSB > OBJ but with the convert to FSB the file is only 10 KB from originally 2 MB.

So my question is, is it normal that nothing happens with the import? Do I need to convert it to a specific type of DXF? Is it even possible to import a 3D DXF file? Every tutorial I found seemed to be more like a 2D floor plan.

Comment: It's possible the model is very far from origin. Is there absolutely no object in the outliner ? You can also try the Adesk Truview converter to get your dxf https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/dwg-trueview/dxf-conversion/td-p/8232353

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file

Comment: No, nothing gets added to the outliner. We got a file directly exportet from CAD as DXF from the maker, but still nothing happens when trying to import.