# Model won't show up when imported

Tags: objects, import, obj

I've imported an .obj file but can't see the object. It shows up listed in the Outliner, but I can't see anything. When I press <kbd>NumPad .</kbd>, I see this shown in the screenshot instead, which is still nothing. I've also tried using <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to try to see it but still nothing. I try to resize, change the mode to see if I can see vertices, like when I import something that is too big or small, but this is all I see. It's not a model I made but I can see it in [Microsoft 3D viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_3D_Viewer) so I know something is in the imported object file.

[image]

Comment: Yes I had this problem too and it seems like a bug that it does not load and immediately you see an empty mesh object in the Outliner. I know it because when i tried closing blender and opening it again and doing the same import again then it was loading for a while before importing it and it worked. But still possible duplicate question to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file

Comment: That's not it. I've opened and closed it several times, I adusted the camera, viewpoint an clipping now too and still  nothing. I've also just left it to load for a while and still nothing.

Comment: can you share a link of the obj file?

Comment: Sure. This is the file. If you can get it to load/see it and it looks all messed up and stretched, that's normal. But other files that have been like this I've been able to import and see. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0TbMn8h5rROd9aJoKbXce6opxnNmbrM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is super huge with dimension of up to 20km

`1` Click the imported object in the Outliner
`2` Press <kbd>N</kbd> and change scale to 0.001
`3` Press <kbd>NumPad .</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yep that sure was it! I could have sworn that was the first thing I did, but it might not have been enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah. the link that is also provided is usually the link they use to mark these questions as duplicates but the answer wasn't so clear about the size, so I added a more simple answer that the first step should definitely be to check the dimensions :D https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271224/142292

Comment: @MushyNarwhal Usually selecting the object in the outliner and pressing Numpad '.' in viewport should center the view on the object - and maybe you even did that - but if you didn't scale the object smaller, with the default clipping end at 1000 m an object with a size of 23000 m remains invisible. Which also means, if for some reason you want to keep that size, you could adjust the viewport clipping values to e.g. start at 100 m and end at 100000 m.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Haha yeah hopefully it helps someone else from looking like a goof like I did cause I didn't double check in the future! Lol

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yeah I just thought I'd done that, but ended up having not. Even shrunk it appears oddly in the camera. I don't want it that big, but if there's ever some reason I need a huge model, I'll do that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @MushyNarwhal I guess you were on the right way but didn't get there completely. I don't know which way it appeared oddly, just note that if you maybe set the clipping end to something like 100000 m to see the model but leave the start at default 0.01 m, this could also cause weird appearance since the range from start to end is too wide.