# IFC 4.0 Import - Can't display model

Tags: modeling, import

I'm fairly new to Blender. I got a Leapfrog ground model and want to import it to Blender but after long import time it simply doesnt show anything. I can see that its been recognized by blender because I can see the Layerstructure on the right hand side of the UI.
Is there anything I do wrong? I'm pretty sure its me being a blender rookie because I dont see any issue with the leapfrog ifc model since I can upload it to Civil3D, several opensource viewers, etc.
[image]

Comment: It's possible that it's too small to be visible. If you left-click and drag the mouse over the centre area where the cursor is, does it hilight more in orange? If so, hit 'S' and drag the mouse to scale the object(s) up. - To add to that, there's just an Empty hilighted in the R/H outliner panel at the moment and hitting 'A' in that panel should select everything there. Then try 'S'caling in the 3D view and see what happens.

Comment: please try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271224/142292

Comment: thanks for the fast reply - I appriciate. Unfortunatly it doesn't worked out. It seems like the model is only the crosshair as shown in the picture. I trieded both ideas to fix it but it only scales the crosshair. Is there anything wrong with the IFC Import in Blender? I dont see any corruption with the leapfrog ifc 4.0. As said it works perfectly in every other big player 3D Modelling software but blender :(

Comment: So I just solved it myself. And this was the issue: In Leapfrog I was using georeference. The coordinate system I used was NAD83 (USA-California) the coordinate origin starts at +500.000km (X) & +500.000km (Y) this is used to prevent coordinates to become negative. Blender thinks its 500.000km far from the origin and therefore it just didnt display on my current view. TBH I didnt test it out yet, but I'm pretty sure this would be the issue.