# can't see objects in 3d viewport

Tags: 3d-view

can't see objects in 3d viewport regardless of clipping. There seems to be inconsistencies in the 3d viewports. Often when importing an object they appear in the outline but not in the viewport. Sometimes if I open a second 3d viewport, the object shows, but not others. Please see the attached screen grab.
[image]

Comment: try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271224/142292

Comment: Is everything here in the default positions? Is this the default blender cube and camera?

Comment: I guess just a mystery