# IFC/OBJ Import doesn't show anything (scale is not the problem)

Tags: modeling, import, obj

I asked the question a couple of days ago already but couldn't get a solution yet:

I tried to import IFC 2x3 & 4.0 once its done importing (which takes up to 2h to read a 51MB IFC file, which is such a long import time anyway) it doesnt show anything. I can see the diffrent layers of my 3D Model but thats it. I tried to scale it up since ppl told me its a matter of scaling. I selected the model (it marks the center-crosshair in orange, which is weird since the crosshair is not my model) pressed "S" to scale it but only the crosshair gets scaled.

Also tried this [Unable to see anything after importing .obj file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file/271224#271224) but didn't worked neither.
Seems like this guy got the exact same problem [imported Obj file not showing even after zoom out or zoom in](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272279/imported-obj-file-not-showing-even-after-zoom-out-or-zoom-in)

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So I just solved it myself. And this was the issue: In Leapfrog I was using georeference. The coordinate system I used was NAD83 (USA-California) the coordinate origin starts at +500.000km (X) & +500.000km (Y) this is used to prevent coordinates to become negative. Blender thinks its 500.000km far from the origin and therefore it just didnt display on my current view. TBH I didnt test it out yet, but I'm pretty sure this would be the issue.