# Import error : how can I see .obj objects correctly in Blender?

Tags: import, error, obj

I wanna import .obj file with texture to make city scene.

So I downloaded  mesh  : .obj ,  material : .mlt  , texture : .jpg ..

Then I imported .obj in blender and I successed.

But I couldnt see any object.
How can I see it ?

[image]

Comment: I see the scale is set to 100. Theoretically you may be inside an enormous object, too large to see the edges. What happens if you turn the scale down to 1?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But although I changed scale to 0.1 ,1 , 100  , It isnt work. 

.obj file has vertexs correctly. but I couldnt any object... blender is too hard for me.

Comment: I solved this problem. The object was created in 0,0,0 , but "in model view transformation" , the vertexs were far away from 0,0,0. [I found the solution here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file) thank you