# Why does Blender GIS not bring in a map and locks up the program

Tags: height-map

I've loaded Blender GIS add on - As soon as I click on "OK" to bring in the Google map, I get a black screen and my tools are gone and/or frozen (see image).

[image]

I've reinstalled - same issue. I'm sure it's simple and I'm a complete newbie.

Comment: That is a third-party addon, not part of Blender so questions about it are off-topic here.

Comment: Your import only brought in an image as seen in the outliner. Either it is too big, or corrupted. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file