# Viewport does not display full image

Tags: 3d-view, image

I have a relatively simple blender image (walls of a house), and my computer is reasonably top-shelf.  However, blender is not showing me the entire image while I'm editing it.  What's worse is that the part it's not showing is the part that's closest to me, so I can't even get to the part of the image that I'm trying to work on.  I've includes two pictures: one of my system's specs and one of my house design with portions of the wall (nearest to you) that are missing from the image.  Video card is NVIDIA GeForce.

This seems to be a memory issue to me, like blender is not using all of the memory my system will allow it to use.  I have the memory limit (userpref/editing) set to "0" (which my system says means "unlimited").  Any thoughts as to what I can check/look at/etc. to keep it from doing this?  Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Computer System Info][image: Image Problem]

Comment: check your clip distance http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554

Comment: BINGO!  Thank you, cegaton, I think that was the key ... :)