# Objects disappear when zooming in in perspective view?

Tags: 3d-view

When I am in my camera view, I can see my scene objects fine. But when I go to the user perspective and zoom in on those objects, they disappear. How can I fix this?

[image: There was a bear there but it disappeared.]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport. The camera has its own clipping values which probably are good enough in order to preview objects as expected. When you leave camera mode, clipping values of 3D Viewport are taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

The op is not in camera view, you have to lower your clip settings in the N panel View tab of the 3dview

[image: clipping settings]

Comment: You're right i misread the question and edit it