# How to stop vertices behind other vertices from displaying

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

There is a control at the bottom of the 3d viewer that hides vertices, edges, and faces that aren't visible. But only if the view is close in, and that often isn't what I need, I need to be able to see the context while I'm working on something large that needs something small within it adjusted. It helps to turn off all Mesh Display Overlays, but only up to a point. I also hide what I can or move objects temporarily to another layer. Things still get in the way when the object is large enough, which often happens. I find myself hiding and unhiding sections of meshes, which  takes time that seems a waste. So I wonder if there is a control somewhere that just flat hides vertices and all when they are behind other faces, no matter the viewing distance. Is there?

Comment: When working with large models which have some tiny details [clipping values might be changed](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport) in order to see what's going on when zoomed in. This won't help hiding mesh components though. There's *Limit Selection to Visible* similar to your description but it turns out you're aware of that so I don't think I understand what's the problem.

Comment: @MrZak When i'm not close to the mesh, toggling Limit Selection To Visible makes no difference. I do note it says 'clipped with depth buffer'. Is it possible that needs to be reset?

Comment: @MrZak - Okay, i see now i can adjust the Clip End distance down to a low number, and that gets rid of the problem, and it also looks like it will help me see what i'm trying to see when i'm inside buildings, which had also been a big problem. I'd adjusted it up to a really high number so my landscapes would never be clipped, and didn't realize what else that affected.