# How to fix 3D view cutoff

Tags: 3d-view

my 3d view window seems to cut off the view
[image]

is there a way to fix this

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Answer (score 1):

Clipping options for the 3D view are here :

[image]

These values are different from the camera options (you may need it also) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Key <kbd>N</kbd> to open the *3D Viewport's Properties panel*. Go to *View dropdown > Clip:* and increase the *End:* value.

*Picture from cetagon's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport):*

[image]