# Meshes went crazy (shaky)

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view

*Hey all!*

Little trouble here.

Meshes went crazy (shaky) when moving around in both viewport and rendered views.

i have a really huge scene. Some objects are very large and some very small.

This happens only to small objects.

Tried playing with clip distances, tried scaling everything up or down with no luck.

Video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86Th-HOGY9Y&feature=youtu.be

[image]

*Thank You*

Comment: If you can't upload the file to Blend-Exchange then I would suggest creating a version of the file that has the least amount in it but still shows the problem by removing anything that isn't necessary and then upload to Blend-Exchange. For example, is it necessary for *all* objects to be in the scene to show the problem? Bear in mind that some people won't bother downloading a file if it is too big.

Comment: Your problem seems to be just clipping flickering.. Clip distance is set from 1mm to 1km, it's too much. Try increasing Start for the clipping distance in the Properties shelf of the 3D viewport > View rolllout. Related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is gone after scaling up shaky objects and then scaling up all the stuff in the world to match the proportions accordingly.

And the problem was not just clipping flickering since it caused real distortion, which was also visible in rendered view.

Thanks Everyone for the attention.

UPDATE: The real problem was the huge distance from the center of the project (grid).
So if you are having similar problems - try moving problematic stuff near the center.

Peace