# Why is my object disappearing unless is close?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

I don't know why, its been a while since I've been on blender but I've opened my project and everything in rendered is blue unless this object (that gray guy, he shouldnt be gray) is close I can not see it and it sinks behind the blue. I might just have a box checked somewhere or it might be something dumb. I am using version 2.7.7

[image]

Comment: That looks like the default world background color for Blender internal in the older 2.4# and 2.5# versions. When was the last time you used Blender?

Comment: "unless its really close"? what does this mean?

Comment: If the issue is with the camera's distance to the object then you need to adjust the clip distance. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554

Comment: As for the grey guy, you need to fix the materials, but please ask that as a different question.