# Volume Scattering problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, materials, volumetrics

Good day!

I would love to have a fog in my project, but I couldn't make it happen, because my project has a giant island which I want to make all foggy, but Volume Scattering seems to not work normally when the scales of stuff is really big.

Maybe it is a bug...

I hope Blender will treat 1mm objects the same as 1.000.000km objects one day...

Comment: Let's put it in another way. Are you going to see object of 1mm and 1km in the same way while in the heavy fog ? Also - 1 million km ? Well, Blender will treat it as usual, your hardware won't.

Comment: My system handles millions of km well but various artifacts arise when the sizes are too small or too big. I mean it could be like in vector graphics. Everything stays the same no matter the size.

Now I can't use the cool volume scattering feature just because everything in my scene is very large.. Yes, I could remake everything into smaller scale but I would need to redo all the animations and I still would not be sure if Volumetrics is going to work fine...

Comment: You can test it yourself. 
Create a new empty project ->add World Volume Scattering->add a light source->tweak all the parameters so everything's working okay-> and scale up high the same setup and try to tweak the parameters again and it's not working anymore... When I adjust the Density of Volume Scatter I can only get totally black result or totally fog-absent result...

Comment: As I said, your hardware will not (more than likely). The artifacts you see on big objects are caused by [cliiping flicker](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport) which will happen in any case on big objects, and that's the end of precision by graphic card. *Millions* of *kilometers* ? Maybe it's possible to handle that, but.. why ?