# Is there a way to reset the camera to avoid clipping?

Tags: camera

During a session editing mesh creating shape keys, I could no longer get close up views due to clipping. Having tried a few solutions from the on-line manual I remain baffled. The only other objects in the scene are one light and one camera. Is there a way to reset the camera for close up viewing with no clipping?

Comment: There is no function to dynamically set the clipping distance in an automatic way if that is what you are asking. To set the clip distance read this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>Num .</kbd> (dot on numpad) Blender will center 3d-view around selection, and move view as close as it possible with considering of
cliping settings and size of bunch of selected objects