# Trying to zoom towards object for more detail, but zooming through object instead

Tags: 3d-view

I'm a Noob. I was working through a tutorial when I hit some keys causing the problem below (I was creating faces between vertices... holding shift & right clicking the vertices to select, then clicking F to create the faces)

Before I was able to zoom (scroll) toward the object to see the the mesh in finer detail without going through the mesh. Now I just zoom straight through the mesh. So I start to see the mesh in more detail as I zoom, then with 1 more turn of the mouse scroll wheel, I zoom straight through my mesh. It appears to be zooming by the same increments.

Anyone know what I have done & how to sort this?

Image 1: What is see before scrolling my mouse forward.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Image 2: What I see after scrolling my mouse forward (It goes through the object). See my clipping values to the right.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Iv'e also just noticed that my background image has disappeared (I only mention this as I assume this is caused by the same problem). 'Background Images' is ticked in the properties region! (I can't show this image as apparently I can't show more than 2 links since my 'reputation' is below 10)

**Edit:**
I just solved my problem & feel like a complete idiot! I was in perspective view, I just pushed '5' on the number pad to change to orthographic view & it solved both my problems above :)

Comment: try hitting the "." button on the number pad to reset your view (with an object or face selected).

Comment: If you mean parts of mesh disappear when you zoom in then see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Comment: Thank your for your replies. The "." button has not stopped this (but is a good tip). I also don't think it has anything to do with clipping. It wasn't doing this before & the clip start & end values are the same as before. Before it zoomed with smaller increments as I got closer to the mesh, but now it zooms by the same increments for each mouse scroll & just zooms right through the mesh

Comment: @RichardMcIntosh can you please [edit] your question and add an image that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Maybe it would help to reset the center point for zoom http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point If you really think this isn't related to clipping (which appears to be from your description) please include some screenshots of whole 3d viewport with clipping values for the properties shelf shown