# I'm having some trouble with textures warping instead of flexing with the surface

Tags: uv

This is my first project in Blender, so I'm pretty ignorant.

First, I've tried manually unwrapping this surface by defining seams (as seen in many tutorials), but I'm having a lot of trouble because there are just so many tiny bits of mesh that I can't select the correct ones, Especially since they disappear when I zoom in. Smart unwwrap sort of works, but the image is stretching instead of bending. So am I pretty much stuck trying to define seams, or is there a way to change the way the image map interacts with the surface curvature? [image: I feel like this is almost there]

[image: But the image is distorting on the page bend]

Comment: Geometry of the mesh disappears when zooming most likely due to [clipping in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport), it's possible to adjust them. It would help if you show the magazine mesh in edit mode (what toplogy does it have) and UV map; if possible, [upload the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). Usually yes, you should define good UV map to avoid stretching of the image, in this case likely stretched texture has less area on UV map than the rest of faces.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The model was one I purchased and converted, so I didn't want to upload it to protect the original creator. After following your tips I see that the mesh, even when unwrapped, is a mess. Rather than try to fix it up, I'm going to start over with my own model, which was partially done before I decided to buy one. I'm having  much better luck working on my model because of your guidance. Thanks again!