# My image won't render. Every time i go to render, all I got is a grey screen

Tags: rendering

I have tried many methods and none of them worked! I tried blender render and cycles render, checked that everything was able to render, and i even tried re-doing the project all over! Anyone have anyway i can fix this? Ill add the blend file.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/3gdy6rf3zg6xvkg/thing.blend  (File was to big for other options, so mediafire I guess)
[image]

[image: See.]

Comment: Please add the .blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Also, adding some screen grabs to your original post using the "edit" botton and the "phpto" icon in the edit bar.

Comment: Ok, I added a blend file and some screenshots. I hope it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) and [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason number 7 on [this post:](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67491/1853)

[OBJECTS ARE NOT WITHIN THE RANGE OF CAMERA CLIPPING](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

You have a scene with huge objects. Each of your figures is tall as a skyscraper.

The camera clipping distance is set to a short range that does not encompass your scene.

[image]

Increase the End clip distance.

[image]

But as a piece of unwanted advice: in Blender it is better to work in a scale that matches the real world. Physics, and other simulations, depth of field and lighting will behave differently depending on the scale.

READ ALSO: [Why does part of my model disappear when I zoom in on it in the 3D Viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport)