# doing a large scale project but my View is Locked

Tags: modeling

i  need the edges of the plane to stop dissappearing when i rotate/scale can anyone help, the plane is very large kms [image: cbn]

Comment: adjust the clip distance for the 3d vieport.

Comment: ok thnk you others having this problem go here :https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed