# Can't see objects with basic camera

Tags: objects, camera

I did a big scene, but can't see it all in basic camera view. Even in rendered mod.
[image]

but i can see it in with created camera.
[image]
So i thinking there must be some setting for basic camera like for created camera in scene.

Comment: Please show your entire blender window for your first screenshot including the *Properties* menu (Press "N" key if it is not present). Or better yet upload your blend file.

Comment: its looks like u need to change in properties>view higher number for "end" value

Comment: Rumen is right. I had there 10m and that house has like 10,5m. I dont know how mark you comment for usefull so i writing this comment.

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Answer (score 1):

Just scale the whole scene down so that it is going to fit in the camera distance. 
Blender is acting very strange when there are so big scaled scenes

[image]
On the right side, you can also see the limits of the camera (the line)

Comment: Well done sir. You beat me too it.