# OBJ import disappears behind 'screen' when zoomed out

Tags: modeling, objects, interface, import

I'm a newbie but am familiar with CAD and modeling.

I have a strange thing happening after I import a .OBJ file into Blender from IronCAD.There appears to be a vertical plane in the 3D modeling space that cuts through the model when I zoom in and out. I'm not able to see the whole model because I have to zoom in too close for the model to be in front of this strange plane...

Has anyone encountered this before, or know how to get rid of it?

Cheers,
Mike.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does part of my model disappear when I zoom in on it in the 3D Viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because your object is extremely large, as far as Blender is concerned. Try scaling it down, applying the scale, and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adjusting the camera End clipping by pressing 'n' in the viewport,
if you wish to retain the size of the object.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick perfectly, thanks so much for that great insight! I would have never found that. The one thing I can't see anymore though is the grid, maybe it's just a case of resizing that as well...