# Difficulties centering the object on the middle of the screen

Tags: objects, 3d-view, customization

I have some difficulties centering the object on the middle of the screen. Infact when I press the mouse wheel the view seems to fly away too fast. This is what happens : on the picture below you see that the object is too far,I don't see it clearly and I can't edit it :

[image: 1]

instead,below you can see that happens when I scroll a little the mouse wheel : the object "disappear" totally.

[image: 2]

I have also attached this [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mj66znUUra0naQJAhPKPMFYWUg7N92nt) to explain better. thanks.

Comment: seems you are running into a viewport clipping issue. Have a look at this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Comment: hello man. I tried to play with the start and end clipping values but I haven't been able to fix the problem.

Comment: From the dimensions I see that the object is quite large 2000 the the y dimension and the clipping distance of of the viewport in your attached image is 1000 try setting it to 5000 and the near clipping distance to 0,0001

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem by Centering the thing I want to look at in every angle. Go to top view [numbpad 7], drag things I want to look at to the centre of my view by holding [shift] and [mouse 3]. Do the same with view from the front and from the right/left. When that's done you should be able to interact with your thing perfetly.

Another way to zoom in slowly is by holding [ctrl] nad dragging with [mouse3].

Yet another way to wiew you object is by using [shift]+[f] shortcut. This shortcut lets you use your WASD keys and mouse as if you were playing a videogame. With [Q] and [E] you can move up and down.