# Why corners cut

Tags: node-editor

This is a square with a thickness. It is only ok from Top view. As I rotate to other views this is happening, corners are cut. in front view it actually becomes hollow. When i do the same thing on a new blender file it is ok.
I have something else on a different plane with high polly objects. could it be the reason?

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what you mean, screenshots often help, you might [edit] you question with at least one. As a guess you describe clipping in viewport, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Comment: Thank you very very very much Mr. Zak. It is the camera. I didnt have a camera and no mesh. when i put camera everything comes ok. Thanks again.

Comment: .. but your first shot might be to increase the Clip Start and End in the View panel of the properties region (N) to the right side of your 3D view