# Blender only portion of model being rendered

Tags: rendering, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I am rendering a still scene of a house.

it is quite a large mesh, the issue I have is that only half of it is showing up in the camera view and the render.

[image: screenshot of camera view]

[image: screenshot of camera view]

[image: screenshot of camera view]

If you look at the screen shots you might see what you mean, it looks like half the mesh is being swallowed. I've been searching for answers and can't find. It's driving me mad.

Thanks

Comment: The camera has a clipping distance, Just increase that or scale your model down.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554

Comment: Thank you, looked really hard for that then it's right there all the time.