# Why render differs from 3D viewport camera view in depth

Tags: rendering

I know there is a question same of my problem.

[How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

I did it but it didn't work so I'm writing here

[image]

---

You can see in first photo when I'm editing there is no problem. but when I render it, it looks like this:

[image]

I just want to render it like the first photo.

---

@vkildu nope it didnt work

[image]

you can see all of this icons are open

Here's the blend file

[image]

Comment: That's the viewport preview (zoom and pan icons on the top right), so I guess you would have to adjust 'Clip End' value of the viewport (not the camera): *N > View > End* -> https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/sidebar.html#view

Comment: Clip start and end of camera and viewport are independent, In the post you linked there is an additional link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Comment: Can't be sure, icons on the top right might be part of camera view if zoomed in ... also OP posted the link to the other q  so I assume OP tried to adjust the end value of the camera already @vklidu

Comment: @brockmann Sorry I deleted my Q in time you posted A. If you speak about second image, in that case there would be also camera icon, these icons are from image editor. BTW viewport clip does not affect view through camera even in viewport, but only out of camera.

Comment: Right, might be the icons of the image editor... who knows. IMHO the OP should clarify what he is doing and what *exactly* is "not working" before anything else and guessing about it all day long @vklidu

Comment: @Burak I was asking to check Plane object, which I see disabled for viewport. From your screen I cant see. Please attach your blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let us see whole setup. Thanks

Comment: In the camera settings you can visualize the render clip distance using Viewport Display>Limits. Can you enable that and show it on a screengrab of your scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *3D viewport* camera view use the same clipping parameter as final render (so there is not a reason to think clipping is issue).

I think your problem lays in disabled **Plane** object in *Outliner editor* that **is not disabled from rendering**.

[image]

Click on *Filter* icon and click on *Camera* icon to see what objects are set to be rendered. Ensure if this object is OFF from rendering as well.

[image]

Comment: it didnt work im tried all of this icons are open

Comment: yes im checked all icons and all icons are open. Now im uploaded and link is "[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=P8gl3RVw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/P8gl3RVw/)" thank you. im appreciate for your help

Comment: ok thanks for everything.

Comment: Number 12 on the list: [why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: @susu I tried to react in chat, but Im not sure if get notification or not ... https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54933080#54933080