# Weird Rendered Product from Cycle

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Sorry if this is just a simple question, but I have been trying to render an image for my project using the cycle engine. This is what i see in the 3D viewport

[image]

Everything looks perfectly fine, but when I try to render it, the end product looks like this

[image]

I cannot understand why there is patch of color blocking my view at the right side of the image.
Would be really appreciate it if anyone could offer any help to solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome, it could be a hidden object, take a look at your outliner an search for an object with the eye icon close [Like this](https://youtu.be/JM-Z4F3WtmI?t=337)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185735/why-render-differs-from-3d-viewport-camera-view-in-depth?answertab=votes#tab-top