# Can't see any of objects in blender or the grid?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, transforms

It seems all of my objects are in some far away place I cant even see the grid or tell zoomed in or out I am. When I try to grab the object and change the location back to origin it goes back to its original position. I am just really confused. When I tried adding a simple mesh cube it does not even show up. Any solutions or advice? I really can't start over.[image: This is what the my layout page looks like now.][image: I am trying to grab and move the object here, Its location is displayed but when I grab and move I cannot see the object.]

Comment: It is probably your camera clipping settings....[related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)