# Why does sometimes the model render incorrectly?

Tags: scene

[image]

I took this in scene view. See the bottom part of my model it is invisble and when i move the view the model cracked.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Check the clip distance. read:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport and 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance/5202#5202

Comment: @susu it doesnt seems to be clipping. There are transparent also part in front. Edges arelike pixelated. Something with transparency?

Comment: Try delete material or attach file with part of model, where issue still visible https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com