# narrow view, model to big. viewport to small

Tags: 3d-view

The view is very narrow, see image.
Also the models disappear...

How can I make the view bigger?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a Clipping issue, open the N panel > View > View > tweak the Clip Start and End values

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport

Answer (score 1):

*Side note: I don't have access to Blender right now, so I will do what I can from memory and what I can find online. Do let me know if this need details, and I'll edit my answer later once I'm back to my personal workstation.*

---

Unless a technical reason prevents you from it, you should scale down your scene to a reasonable size, even real-life size if possible.
If you can't, then change the viewport and camera clipping planes.

### Scaling the scene

To preserve every object's position relative to each other and within the 3D world, we'll can use the 3D cursor to scale them down from the world center.

First, make sure the 3D cursor is at the world origin by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to World.

Then, set the [pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html) to 3D cursor.

[image]

To help see the scale, I personally like to create a cube that's the dimensions of a human:

- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Mesh > Cube
- <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>. This should have moved the cube to the floor.
- <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> back to object mode. In the viewport sidebar, Item tab, Dimensions section, set the dimensions of the cube to X and Y: 45cm, Z: 174cm. This is the average of a human male.

Now press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all your objects, hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and click your human cube twice to deselect it.
Press <kbd>S</kbd> to enter the scale modal operator, and move your mouse around to scale down all the selected objects. Once you feel like their dimensions are logical compared to the human cube, use <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> or <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to validate the scaling.

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything again, then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale. This is to prevent issues down the line.

### Change clipping planes

If Scaling isn't possible, go in the viewport sidebar, View tab, Clipping. You should see start and end clipping values.
End clipping is how far you can see, start by updating this one first. Once done, you should also update the start clipping, as **having them too far from each other can cause issues**. A safe bet is to set it to whatever the greatest value you can without seeing any problematic clipping.

Once you are done with that, select your camera. Press <kbd>numpad</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to set your viewport into camera view. If you have clipping issues, you need to change that camera's clipping settings too.

In the Properties editor > Camera data tab, clipping panel, you can change the camera's clipping there.