# Is there a separate clipping range for the viewport versus the camera (camera clipping distance acts different)?

Tags: camera, clipping

blender denizens, I have a puzzle for you:

With "View" "Clip" "End" set to 5000m (start at .1), I'm getting clipping of an object in camera view (at approx. 200m or so).  Viewport shows the mesh fine.
Here is the camera view from about 200m:

[image]

Here is the camera view from about 175m where you start to see the clipping 'wall':

[image]

Here is the camera view from about 150m and the mesh is fully visible, so inside some kind of auxiliary clipping wall:

[image]

And here is the viewport from about the first 200m position:

[image]

Here is the blend file to poke around in.  Hopefully its some setting I've messed up.  Please let me know if you can replicate the clipping issue and/or if you have any input.  Appreciate your time!

[chibi test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F8Qqe4hA2Y6BMmefnhTPEMutyOsDY9RE/view?usp=drive_link)

Sorry if it's not protocol to share files or links. Give me a heads up and I'll edit

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the viewport and the camera have independent clip settings.  You can find the camera's settings in properties/data/lens.  When you are looking at your 3D viewport through your camera's view (which you are doing in all but the fourth picture above), it will use the camera's clip settings rather than the viewport's clip settings.

However, these clip settings don't act differently, other than the fact that they might have different values.  The 3D viewport is, really, a render, from an implicit camera that works the same way that the explicit camera does.