# Orthographic view graphical artifacts

Tags: 3d-view, objects

I'm having some problems with orthographic view which I don't know how to solve. Regardless of what mode I'm in (object or edit), I can see through my meshes as if x-ray was on. Rotating my view also causes strange artifacts on my meshes, like in the picture below, and they sometimes disappear entirely until I rotate the view again.

It makes it very hard to work with my meshes in orthographic view, and perspective view does not always satisfy my needs. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What are your clipping settings? Do the artifacts go away if you increase the start clip value?

Comment: @gandalf3 It was actually my end clip value! It works great now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1385/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to gandalf3, I found out it was my clipping distance settings for the viewport. The ending distance was set too high. I've set it to 5000 and it's perfect now.