# Mesh becomes see-through in edit mode

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode

As illustrated in the screenshot, the geometry on the non-visible part of the mesh is visible in edit mode, even when the viewport shading mode is set to `Solid`.

[image]

It gets difficult to see and select geometry efficiently when this happens. I've observed that this happens when I set the units to centimeters (also in the screenshot).

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround? If this is a bug, where is the best place to report it?

You can download my .blend file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42899760/gun.blend) (size 7.53 MB).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For reasons I can't fully comprehend, the cause of this weird display behavior is the view clipping distance. The issue was resolved when I set the clip end to its default value of 10m.

Still not sure whether this is a bug.

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me as well; my issue was the clip start distance … I had to up it from 0.001 to 0.01. I think [this question is related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view/1387#1387).

Answer (score 13):

It's not a bug, it's a feature! It's called "Limit Selection to visible", and it limits selection to the visible faces. To enable the Limiting, you have to click this button.

[image]

Comment: I tried toggling that button as well. Doesn't change how the mesh displays, and even selects non-visible (or rather shouldn't-be-visible) faces! This is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: I can't figure out what your problem is, but if you create a new file and then append your model, it will be fixed.

Comment: Appending seems to resolve the issue. Workaround found, I guess. I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anybody can determine the cause of the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Traduci

@ApoorvaJ Perhaps the problem is into the file model it self: maybe something has been corrupted somewhere in it. But someonewithpc is right: his/her answer usually is the way to go to activate/deactivate such feature and it works perfectly (when everything works properly in the blender file). I use it a lot while modelling to make selections and to see through the model accordingly with modelling needs. Also, if you observe your own screenshot you will notice that such option is active as well as someonewithpc highlights in the answer.