# What is the unit of measure with the ruler tool?

Tags: units, measurement

When I use the ruler tool, it gives a very accurate reading, with many numbers past the decimal point.

However, what am I reading?  Is it giving me this in meters, centimeters, inches?  And is there a way to specify this in preferences somewhere?

Comment: By default it uses blender units (BU), which are equivalent to meters. You can specify imperial or metric units in the scene panel. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17966/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18142/599

Answer (score 5):

By default it uses blender units (BU), which are equivalent to meters. You can specify imperial or metric units in *Properties > Scene > Units*:

[image]
[image]

Also see:

- [Blender units vs metric](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17966/599)
- [How do blender units and meters, feet, or yards correlate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254/599)
- [What is a sensible scale to work with?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18142/599)