# Edges not properly displayed in 3d view

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edges

I worked on a model in large scale and then scaled down the model. Now I am not able to clearly see the edges in the model in 3d view. Is this a known Blender issue. Is there a way to increase the thickness of the edges that are displayed in the 3d view port?

[image]

Comment: Probably adjusting [clipping in 3d View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view-viewport-clipping) may solve that

Comment: It would make it a little easier to tell what's wrong if you used a non-lossi format such as .png, the compression artifacts make it a little difficult to see.

Comment: I will upload a PNG once I reach home. Thanks

Comment: Just noticed that the text on the image has white background. How did that happen? Is it a stackexchange feature or imgur feature.

Comment: no @FazilAbdulLathif I replaced the text it was heavily artifacted almost illegible.

Comment: @zeffii Thanks for that. I am using stack exchange for the first time. It would have been a really good feature otherwise :)

Comment: I just tried changing clipping. Now it shows the model in 3d view in orthographic mode. This is enough for me to work for now. The size of the object is 3.5cm x 5.5 cm x 9.8 cm. And the clipping I have set now is Start 1mm and end 300m.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oSQKWgu.png

Comment: perspective looks weird though. I have had this issue before but never thought it was the clipping.

Answer (score 1):

Try to adjust in properties panel the start clip.Should solve the problem. Or you can try to turn your modifiers off in the viewport to sea the lines more clearly.

Comment: As suggested by everyone, I tried changing the clip start and end. And I think it is better to work on the object with a larger size and reduce it when required. I have enabled metric and the lowest clip possible is 1mm. Which is small for the model which is in centimeters. So if I increase the size of model, I will be able to work easily and then scale and apply the object once completed.