# why are my meshes looking the way they do

Tags: geometry

please help this is bugging me a ton it looks so weird and i need this for class tommorow.
[image]

there isnt any overlapping faces so i have no idea also its not in wireframe
it looks worse the farther i go out but even up close it looks really bad.

Comment: It may help to edit your .blend file into your question using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/     It does look like overlapping faces though.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/edit-mode-transparent-objects. Looks like z-fighting

Answer (score 1):

It looks like overlapping faces to me, I've had this a lot of times. Try going to the tools bar in Edit Mode and look for "Remove Doubles". If it doesn't help, I don't know what to do. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯