# faces visible through somewhat transparent mesh edges in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, faces

I'm following this tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jJGBzAxXKo

I'm following every step very carefully but for some reason my mesh does not look like the one in the tutorial. Faces are visible through mesh edges. I have the "Limit selection to visible" turned on. The normals are also facing the right way, outside. I've tried to recalculate them few times with no improvement. What is causing this? [image: picture of problem]

Comment: check to see if you have a modifier on your geometry, from the look at the vertical rail, it looks smaller then the geometry lines

Comment: On Blender Stack Exchange, we typically do not thank people in advance - once someone answers, you can thank them by upvoting and accepting their answer.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view/1387#1387