# Please explain how to extrude a 2D curve from SVG

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Can a 2D shape that was created in Illustrator be extruded? The svg file imported successfully, but I have not been able to determine how to extrude the shape into a solid object. Does this require a special add-on?

Comment: No, it doesn't need a special add-on. What type of object is it? Mesh? Curve? Nurbs?

Comment: This has been asked countless times before, see [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve) or [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47825/extruding-vector-files-in-blender) or [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51962/when-importing-svg-from-inkscape-losses-of-color-and-definition) and [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-beziers-nurbs-and-paths)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for being patient. As soon as I posted my question I discovered the post you referenced, which I found very helpful. I converted the shape to a mesh and DUH. From now on I promise to research more carefully before I ask.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **Solidify** modifier.

Select imported object, go to *Modifiers* tab, select *Solidify* and change *Thickness* to desired value.

[image: Solidify]

Comment: For curve objects its always better to use the curve's builtin extruding and beveling options, instead of the solidify modifier

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos why? Solidify gives result with tris, extrude curve gives ngons and... Shading issues (http://imgur.com/SwOYx0T - guess which is which). After converting Curve to Mesh both results are the same (exact same tris topology). Almost the same. Shading still need to be corrected in curve extrude version.

Comment: If you are going to convert to mesh its pretty indifferent, but that is a destructive process and should be avoided. If however you want to keep things non destructive, curve based extrusion  allows direct bevelling, custom bevel shapes and per vertex radius control. You can non destructively fix shading with a *Edge Split* modifier for both solutions

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos question was only about extrusion not bevel, and as long as both method works for this in non destructive manner I don't see the point why "its always better". There are numbers of method how to achieve something like this, for me the best would be to retopologize this mesh and extrude in classical manner. It's always better to have proper topology with quads ;)

Comment: Answer should always strive to be the best overall solution in long term. Generally I'd agree, good topology is always better, but this seems like a logo design question, unless further modeling is required, good topology is not the main concern here. Keeping a curve object "live" and unspoiled is a lot more useful, since it allows easy tweaking and modifying of the logo shape and curvature without having to deal with triangulation and topology issues. If you convert to mesh its a one way trip and won't be able to go back without information loss.

Comment: If however your logo does need heavy mesh based tweaking and modeling,  then starting out with a curve objects is already a bad principle. Curve should just be used as a modelling guide and a quad based mesh should be used instead.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I wasn't recommending converting it to mesh. Solidify is non destructive as well. You don't need to explain curves for me :) My question was why it's better. It's not better or not. It's just different approach.