# How do I delete the faces on this SVG?

Tags: bezier-curves, faces, outliner, svg

I uploaded an Illustrator SVG to Blender and opened it.
The problem is that the SVG now has some extra faces I didn't need. I need only the outline/curves and also I can't find anymore the face selection.
[This is what i'm trying to do so you can understand more](https:///www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt1ml7owo94)[image: this is the svg]

[image]

Comment: Once the curves have been imported they are no longer an SVG, but regular curves. Curves have no faces unless they are converted to a mesh and edited. Note also that each "layer" on an illustrator file will be exported as a different curve object.

Comment: Ok but what the duck is that grey area?

Comment: Ducks and geese are not something I know about.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51962/when-importing-svg-from-inkscape-losses-of-color-and-definition/51973#51973 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill/75736#75736 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion/56352#56352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn to "None" the Fill Mode in the Curve Properties.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the man!

Comment: @Uroš Please mark the answer as accepted ✓, so the whole world knows FFeller is the man :).