# More efficient mesh than zigzag?

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, optimization

I have a svg with a lot of edges (probably in the 100's of thousands). I was noticing that when I start extruding there's a lot more processing that needs to be done. Is there a way to simplify this zigzag pattern of things seen in the mesh view so that there are less edges? For example, removing all of these inner edges in this shape:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this help
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/how-do-i-delete-the-faces-on-this-svg#164308 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=231&v=ctwiT8LYjVQ

Comment: Hello and welcome. Press `A` to select all vertices then `X` > *Limited Dissolve*

Comment: I would use a _Decimate Modifier_ set to _Planar_.