# Is there a way to import .svg files into Blender so it honors the .svg layers and will look the same without plane collisions?

Tags: import, svg

I have an SVG file that is all outlines and imports nicely into Blender EXCEPT that each segment imports into the same positional plane so what looks correct in the SVG file shows the letters merged together where they intersect.  I know why it does this, but it'd be nice if the imported SVG would look the same without this issue, after all that's what the layers in SVG files are for.

I know after importing I can edit the layers and adjust their Y position to shift one set of letters in front of the other but I was hoping to avoid having to do this since I'd like to have a workflow that works for a lot of these situations.

I cannot use booleans and cutting out the shape of the intersecting "t" from the "D" isn't an option, I need each letter's shape fully in tact so they can be used further in an animation.

**So, is there a simple way to import SVG files with layers so they don't collide or will I have to resort to adjusting the positions to duplicate the layering in the SVG?**

Here are the images to help show what I'm referring to:

**SVG File: Notice that the "t" is in front of the "D"**
[image: Next Day Videos SVG logo]

**Blender rendering of the SVG file imported:**

[image: Logo imported into Blender]

Comment: Could you link a sample svg?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51962/when-importing-svg-from-inkscape-losses-of-color-and-definition and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/ I know of no way to Z stack objects natively, maybe sort them in Z after the fact with something like https://blenderartists.org/t/distribute-objects-addon-another-array-addon/1218859 , it wont attempt to conserve any original Z ordering, objects will be sorted arbitrarily, although if they are read and created by their Z index it might coincidentally be correct

Comment: As far as I know, the SVG layers hold no 3-dimensional information. How should Blender decide how much height difference there should be between the layers? They are 2-dimensional with zero height, so that's exactly how Blender stacks them above each other. Because even if Blender might be able to give them the correct order, the height is still 0 and that causes Z-fighting.

Comment: SVG do have the concept of layers, although they carry different meaning. They can be translated to Z depth in 3D. But since it's a subjective translation, you'll have to use a custom made importer