# How to set the priority of two intersecting planes

Tags: python

There are two planes that were added via *Import > Images as Layers*.
They are located at the same coordinate along the Z axis.
Is it possible to manually prioritize which plane is displayed in front of the other?
For example, like you do in Photoshop for 2D in the form of layers.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51973/19307

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Is it possible to somehow use rendering passes, compositing? Pass index? I’m using EEVEE

Comment: Never tried it myself, but sounds feasible, you can set up several render layers, or different passes or any other method to separate them into different layers, and composite them in whatever order you like. Beware that the realtime compositor doesn't support live preview of layers or passes at the moment.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Can you show how to do this using different passes? EEVEE

Comment: If you have a different question please use the [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top right. Be sure to search through existing ones first, it may have already been answered before